# Python Import Statement bug?

Tags: python, file, debugging, import

****I solved this below****: I think it may be helpful to others in the future, so I'm keeping my question up vs. taking it down. It's a python vs. other language nested file import issue. However if anyone understands the intricacies of why this is so in python an explanatory answer would greatly be appreciated.

I had my code running fine with a file directory setup like this:

```
sniffer //folder
 -__init__.py
 -Sniffer.py
 -database.py

I switched it to:
Main
 -snifferLaunch.py
 -flashy
   --sniffer
    ---Sniffer.py
    ---database.py
```

In theory if I change the imports to find the folders it should still run the same way...

I was under the impression that importing a python file could be done even if it was nested. For example

> import Sniffer // in snifferLaunch should go through each file and try to find a Sniffer.py file.

I however found this to be false, did I misunderstand this? So I tried looking at an example which imports files like this:

import flashy.sniffer.Sniffer as Sniffer

This does import a file I believe. When I run it it traces out an error on launch however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snifferLaunch.py", line 19, in <module>
    import flashy.sniffer.Sniffer
  File "/Users/tai/Desktop/FlashY/flashy/sniffer/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
  File "/Users/tai/Desktop/FlashY/flashy/sniffer/__init__.py", line 107, in forInFile
  File "/Users/tai/Desktop/FlashY/flashy/sniffer/__init__.py", line 98, in runFlashY
  File "/Users/tai/Desktop/FlashY/flashy/sniffer/__init__.py", line 89, in db
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getDecompiledFiles'
```

This would normally cause me to go look for a getDecompiledFiles function. The problem is that no where in the code is there a getDecompiledFiles. There is a get_Decompiled_Files function.

My code looks something like this (non essential parts removed). Do you see my bug? I searched the entire project and could not find a getDecompiledFiles function anywhere. I don't know why it is expecting to have an attribute of this...

snifferLaunch:

```
import flashy.sniffer.Sniffer as Sniffer
import flashy.sniffer.database as database
import flashy.sniffer.cleaner as cleaner

def open_websites(line):
  #opens a list of websites from local file "urlIn.txt" and runs the Sniffer on them.
  #It retrieves the swfs from each url and storing them in the local out/"the modified url" /"hashed swf.swf" and the file contains the decompiled swf

    print( "opening websites")
    newSwfFiles = [];
    # reads in all of the lines in urlIn.txt
    #for line in urlsToRead:
    if line[0] !="#":
        newLine = cleaner.remove_front(line);
        # note the line[:9] is done to avoid the http// which creates an additional file to go into. The remaining part of the url is still unique.
        outFileDirectory = decSwfsFolder + "/" + newLine
        cleaner.check_or_create_dir(outFileDirectory)
        try:
            newSwfFiles = Sniffer.open_url(line, []);

        except:
            print " Sniffer.openURL failed"
            pass
        # for all of the files there it runs jpex on them. (in the future this will delete the file after jpex runs so we don't run jpex more than necessary)
        for location in newSwfFiles:


            cleaner.check_or_create_dir(outFileDirectory + "/" + location)
            #creates the command for jpex flash decompiler, the command + file to save into + location of the swf to decompile
            newCommand = javaCommand + "/" + newLine + "/" + location +"/ " + swfLoc +"/"+ location 
            os.system(newCommand)
            print ("+++this is the command: " + newCommand+"\n")
            # move the swf into a new swf file for db storage
            oldLocation = swfFolder + location;
            newLocation = decSwfsFolder + "/" + newLine + "/" + location + "/" + "theSwf"+ "/"
            cleaner.check_or_create_dir(newLocation )
            if(os.path.exists(oldLocation)):
                # if the file already exists at that location do not move it simply delete it (the) duplicate
                if(os.path.exists(newLocation +"/"+ location)):
                    os.remove(oldLocation)
                else:
                    shutil.move(swfFolder + location, newLocation)
        if cleanup:
            cleaner.cleanSwf();
                # newSwfFiles has the directory file location of each new added file: "directory/fileHash.swf"
def db():
  database.get_decompiled_files()

def run_flashY(line):
  #Run FlashY a program that decompiles all of the swfs found at urls defined in urlIn.txt. 
  #Each decompiled file will be stored in the PaperG Amazon S3 bucket: decompiled_swfs. 

    #run the program for each line
    #open all of the websites in the url file urlIn.txt
    open_websites(line)
    #store the decompiled swfs in the database
    db()
    #remove all files from local storage
    cleaner.clean_out()
    #kill all instances of firefox

def for_in_file():
  #run sniffer for each line in the file
  #for each url, run then kill firefox to prevent firefox buildup
  for line in urlsToRead:
    run_flashY(line)
  cleaner.kill_firefox()

#Main Functionality 
if __name__ == '__main__':
  #initialize and run the program on launch     
  for_in_file()
```

The Sniffer File:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
import shutil
import sys
import re
import os
import hashlib
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
import glob
import thread
import httplib
from collections import defaultdict
import cleaner



a=[];
b=[];
newSwfFiles=[];
theURL='';
curPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#firebug gets all network data
fireBugPath = curPath +'/firebug-1.12.8b1.xpi';
#netExport exports firebug's http archive (network req/res) in the form of a har file
netExportPath = curPath +'/netExport.xpi';

harLoc = curPath +"/har/";
swfLoc = curPath +"/swfs";
cleanThis=True

#remove har file(s) after reading them out to gather swf files
profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile();
profile.add_extension( fireBugPath);
profile.add_extension(netExportPath);
hashLib = hashlib.md5()

#firefox preferences
profile.set_preference("app.update.enabled", False)  
profile.native_events_enabled = True
profile.set_preference("webdriver.log.file", curPath +"webFile.txt")
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.DBG_STARTER", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.12.8");
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.addonBarOpened", True);
profile.set_preference('extensions.firebug.consoles.enableSite', True)
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.console.enableSites", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.script.enableSites", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.net.enableSites", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.previousPlacement", 1);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation", "on");
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.onByDefault", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.defaultPanelName", "net");
#set net export preferences
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.autoExportToFile", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.saveFiles", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.autoExportToServer", False);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.Automation", True);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.showPreview", False);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.pageLoadedTimeout", 15000);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.timeout", 10000);
profile.set_preference("extensions.firebug.netexport.defaultLogDir",harLoc);
profile.update_preferences();
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile);

def open_url(url,s):
  #open each url, find all of the har files with them and get those files. 

    theURL = url;
    time.sleep(6);
    #browser = webdriver.Chrome();
    browser.get(url); #load the url in firefox
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    time.sleep(3); #wait for the page to load
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/5);")
    time.sleep(1); #wait for the page to load
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4);")
    time.sleep(1); #wait for the page to load
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3);")
    time.sleep(1); #wait for the page to load
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
    time.sleep(1); #wait for the page to load
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    searchText='';
    time.sleep(20); #wait for the page to load

   # print(browser.page_source);
   #close the browser and get all the swfs from the created har file.
   #uses the a & b arrays to find the swf files from generated har files
    get_swfs_from_har()
    #clean out the slashes
    clean_f_slashes()
    #get all files
    get_all_files()

    #ensure that some files were gained
    assert a != []
    assert b != []
    assert newSwfFiles != []

    #if the files (har, swf, out) should be cleaned out do so. This can be toggled for dubugging
    if(cleanThis):
        cleaner.clean_har()

    return newSwfFiles;

def remove_non_url(t):
  #remove matched urls that are not actually urls

    a=[];
    for b in t:
        if(b.lower()[:4] !="http" and b.lower()[:4] != "www."  ):

            if(b[:2] == "//" and b.__len__() >10):
                a.append(theURL+"/"+b[2:]);
            else:
                while((b.lower()[:4] !="http" or b.lower()[:4] !="www."  or b.lower()[:1] !="//") and b.__len__() >10):
                    b=b[1:b.__len__()];
                if( b.__len__() >10):
                    if(b[:1] == "//" ):
                        if not b in a:
                            a.append(theURL+b[2:b.__len__()]);
                    else:
                        if not b in a:
                            a.append(b);
        else:
            if not b in a:
                a.append(b);
    return a;

def get_swfs_from_har():
  #validate that the files in the har are actual swf files
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(harLoc) if re.match((theURL[7:]+ '.*.har'), f)]
    for n in files:
        with open (harLoc + n , "r") as theF:
            textt = theF.read();
            swfObjects= re.findall('\{[^\{]*(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.|\/\/)[^}]*\.swf[^}]+', textt.lower())
            #swfObjects = "".join(str(i) for i in swfObjects)
            for obj in swfObjects:
                l=[]
                otherL=[]
                links = re.findall('(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.|\/\/)[^"]+', obj)
                for url in links:
                    url=url[:url.__len__()-1]
                    ending = url[url.__len__()-6:];
                    if ".swf"  in ending:
                        l.append(url);
                    elif "." not in ending:
                        otherL.append(url);
                for c in l:
                    if not c in a and c.__len__() >20:
                        a.append(c);
                        if(otherL.__len__()>0):
                            theMostLikelyLink=otherL[0];
                            b.append(theMostLikelyLink);
                            ##adds the 1st link after the swf
                            otherL.remove(theMostLikelyLink);
                        else:
                            b.append(None);

def clean_f_slashes():
  #remove unrelated characters from swfs
    for x in a:
        newS='';
        if(',' in x or ';'  in x or '\\' in x):
            for d in x:
                if(d != '\\' and d != ',' and d != ';'):
                    newS+=d;
        else:
            newS=x;
        if "http" not in newS.lower():
            if "www" in newS:
                newS= "http://" + newS;
            else:
                newS = "http://www."+newS
        while(newS[:3]!="htt"):
            newS=newS[1:];
        a.remove(x);
        if(newS.__len__() >15):
            a.append(newS);

def get_all_files():
  #get all of the files from the array of valid swfs

    os.chdir(swfLoc);
    for openUrl in a:
        place = a.index(openUrl);
        try:
            req = Request(openUrl)
            response = urlopen(req)
            fData = urllib2.urlopen(openUrl)
            iText = fData.read()
            #get the hex hash of the file
            hashLib.update(iText);
            hashV =hashLib.hexdigest()+".swf";
            outUrl= get_redirected_url(b[place]);
            #check if file already exists, if it does do not add a duplicate
            theFile = [f for f in os.listdir(swfLoc) if re.match((hashV), f)]
            if hashV not in theFile:
                lFile = open(outUrl+"," +hashV, "w")
                lFile.write(iText)
                lFile.close();
        #except and then ignore are invalid urls. 
        except:
            pass
    #Remove all files less than 8kb, anything less than this size is unlikely to be an advertisement. Most flash ads seen so far are 25kb or larger
    sFiles = [f for f in os.listdir(swfLoc)]
    for filenames in sFiles:
        sizeF = os.path.getsize(filenames);
        #if the file is smaller remove it
        if(sizeF<8000):
            cleaner.remove_file(filenames)
        else:
            newSwfFiles.append(filenames);     
def x_str(s):
  #check if a unicode expression exists and convert it to a string

    if s is None:
        return ''
    return str(s)
def get_redirected_url(s):
  #get the url that another url will redirect to

    if s is None:
        return "";
    if ".macromedia" in s:
        return ""
    browser.get(s);
    time.sleep(20);
    theredirectedurl=cleaner.removeFront(browser.current_url);
    aUrl= re.findall("[^/]+",theredirectedurl)[0].encode('ascii','ignore')
    return aUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... so I actually realized I was going about it wrong.

I still don't know why it was expecting a function that didn't exist but I do have a guess.

I had pulled the `__init__.py` file to use as the snifferLaunch file. This was due to my original misunderstanding of `__init__.py` and assuming it was similar to a main in other languages.

I believe the `__init__.pyc` file was holding an old function that had been outdated. Essentially I believe there was a file that should never have been run, it was outdated and somehow getting called. It was the only file that existed that had that function in it, I overlooked it because I thought it shouldn't be called.

The solution is the following, and the bug was caused by my misuse of `__init__`.

I changed my import statements:

```
from flashy.sniffer import Sniffer
import flashy.sniffer.database as database
import flashy.sniffer.cleaner as cleaner
```

I created new blank `__init__.py`, and `__init__.pyc` files in `flashy/sniffer/`.

This prevented the false expectation for `getDecompiledFiles`, and also allowed the code to be run. I was getting a "cannot find this file" error because it wasn't correctly being identified as a module. Additional information on this would be appreciated if anyone can explain what was going on there. I thought you could run a python file without an init statement however when nested in other folders it appears that it must be opened as a python module.

My file structure looks like this now:

```
Main
 -snifferLaunch.py //with changed import statements
 -flashy
   --sniffer
    ---Sniffer.py
    ---database.py
    ---__init__.py //blank
    ---__init__.pyc // blank
```

It appears to be python vs. other languages issue. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: @hlt, thanks for the edit. Could you explain when to use ' ' to wrap vs leaving it?

Comment: The backticks are usually used for code inside other text and sometimes for other data that is better displayed in a monospaced font (e.g. folder structures, as you did). Personally, I like to wrap paths in them as well for better visual clarity (e.g. the emphasis on it not being normal text), especially if the paths contain other characters normally counted as markdown formatting (mainly `_`, because `_` is equivalent to `*` for italics and bold text). You can find more information about text formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @htl, oh ok thank you. I knew '*' was italics and '**' was for bold text I didn't realize that '_' was as well.